# Inserting a node after a given node in a singly linked list is not working

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert a node into a singly linked list after a given node. However, when I run the test files, it doesn't work and just skips over the function. Is anyone able to shed some light on this issue?

EDITED:
Here is all of my code:

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList: public LinkedListInterface<T>
{
private:
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node* next;
    Node(const T& the_data, Node* next_val = NULL) :
    data(the_data) {next = next_val;}
};

Node *my_list;
int num_items;
public:

LinkedList(void) {
    my_list = NULL;
    num_items = 0;
    cout << "In constructor" << endl;
};
virtual ~LinkedList(void) {
    cout << "In deconstructor" << endl;
    while(my_list != NULL) {
        Node *current = my_list;
        my_list = my_list->next;
        delete current;
    };
};

/*
insertHead

A node with the given value should be inserted at the beginning of the list.

Do not allow duplicate values in the list.
*/
virtual void insertHead(T value)
{
    Node *ptr = my_list;
    Node *temp = my_list;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_items; i++) {
        if (num_items > 0 && temp-> data == value){
            cout << "there is already a node with this value in the list" << 
 endl;
            return;
        }
        temp = temp-> next;
    }
    my_list = new Node(value);
    my_list->next = ptr;
    num_items++;
    cout << "In insertHead" << endl;
};

/*
insertTail

A node with the given value should be inserted at the end of the list.

Do not allow duplicate values in the list.
*/
virtual void insertTail(T value)
{
    cout << "In insertTail" << endl;
    Node *ptr = my_list;
    Node *temp = my_list;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_items;i++) {
        if (num_items >0 && temp->data == value) {
            cout << "there is already a node in the list with this value" << 
   endl;
            return;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(my_list == NULL){
        insertHead(value);
    } 
    else {
        while(ptr != NULL){
            cout << ptr<<" data "<<ptr->data<<" next "<<ptr->next<<endl;
            if(ptr->next == NULL) {
                ptr->next = new Node(value, NULL);
                break;
            }
            else {
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
        }
    }
    num_items++;
};

/*
insertAfter

A node with the given value should be inserted immediately after the
node whose value is equal to insertionNode.

A node should only be added if the node whose value is equal to
insertionNode is in the list. Do not allow duplicate values in the list.
*/
virtual void insertAfter(T value, T insertionNode) 
{
    cout << "In insertAfter"<<endl;
    Node *ptr = my_list;
    Node *temp = my_list;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_items;i++) {
        if (num_items >0 && temp->data == value) {
            cout << "there is already a node in the list with this value" << 
   endl;
            return;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if (my_list == NULL) {
        cout << "the list is empty" << endl;
        return;
    }
    
    int counter = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_items; i++) {
        if (ptr->data == value) {
            counter = i;
            break;
        }
        else {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
    if (counter == -1){
        return;
    }
    
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        if(ptr->data == insertionNode){
            cout << "If branch" << endl;
            Node *new_node = new Node(value, ptr->next->next);
            new_node->next = ptr->next;
            ptr->next = new_node;
            num_items++;
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout << "else branch" << endl;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
};
/*
remove

The node with the given value should be removed from the list.

The list may or may not include a node with the given value.
*/
virtual void remove(T value) 
{
    cout << "In remove" << endl;
    Node *ptr = my_list;
    if (my_list == NULL) {
        cout << "the list is empty - nothing to remove" << endl;
        return;
    }
    int counter = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_items; i++) {
        if (ptr->data == value) {
            counter = i;
            break;
        }
        else {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
    if (counter == -1){
        return;
    }
    if(value == my_list->data) {
        Node *current = my_list;
        my_list = my_list->next;
        delete current;
        num_items--;
    }
    else {
        Node *ptr = my_list;
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            if(ptr->data == value) {
                Node *current = ptr->next;
                ptr->next = ptr->next->next;
                delete current;
                num_items--;
            }
            else{
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
        }
    }
};

/*
clear

Remove all nodes from the list.
*/
virtual void clear()
{
    
    cout << "In clear" << endl;
    Node *ptr = my_list;
    while(ptr != NULL) {
    remove(ptr->data);
    ptr = ptr->next;
    }
};

/*
at

Returns the value of the node at the given index. The list begins at
index 0.

If the given index is out of range of the list, throw an out of range 
exception.
*/
virtual T at(int index)
{
    cout << "In at"<<endl;
    if(index >= num_items || index < 0) {
        throw std::out_of_range("At Error");
    } 
    else {
        Node *ptr = my_list;
        for(int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
            cout << "["<<i<<"]="<<ptr->data<<endl;
            if(i == (index)) { 
                return(ptr->data);
            }
            else {
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
        }
    }
};

/*
size

Returns the number of nodes in the list.
*/
virtual int size()
{
    cout << "In size()" << endl;
    return num_items;
};

/*
toString

Returns a string representation of the list, with the value of each node 
listed in order (Starting from the head) and separated by a single space
There should be no trailing space at the end of the string

For example, a LinkedList containing the value 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 should 
return
"1 2 3 4 5"
*/
virtual string toString()
{
    stringstream ss;
    for(Node *ptr =my_list; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next){
        if (ptr->next == NULL) {
            ss << ptr->data;
            break;
        }
        ss <<ptr->data << " ";
        //cout <<ptr->data << " ";
    }
    return(ss.str());
};

};
```

Here is the test file:

```
INT
insertHead 1
insertTail 2
insertAfter 3 2
size
printList
insertHead 0
insertTail 4
insertAfter 0 50
insertAfter 50 51
size
printList
size
insertHead 1000
size
```

Here is my output file:

```
insertHead 1
insertTail 2
insertAfter 3 2
size 2
printList
1 2
insertHead 0
insertTail 4
insertAfter 0 50
insertAfter 50 51
size 4
printList
0 1 2 4
size 4
insertHead 1000
size 5
```

Here is the key file:

```
insertHead 1
insertTail 2
insertAfter 3 2
size 3
printList
1 2 3
insertHead 0
insertTail 4
insertAfter 0 50
insertAfter 50 51
size 5
printList
0 1 2 3 4
size 5
insertHead 1000
size 6
```

It won't work when I try to insert 3 after 2.

Comment: What do you mean by "skips over the function"? Can you show the test files, please, along with expected output and actual output? How do you know the function is being skipped?

Comment: I mean that it will enter the function but not insert the value. I will edit my code now with all the information

Comment: That's quite a lot of code for something that should be rather simple. All you need is a single loop, and nothing more. That loop is looking for `insertionNode`, and when you find it you append a new node after it.

Comment: In the interest of avoiding you wasting your time, please read [ask] and [example] before posting the edit you're planning.

Comment: As for how to solve the problem with the code you have, then please learn how to use a *debugger*. With a debugger you can step through your code statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values. I also recommend that while you're stepping through the code, use pen and paper to draw the operations you're doing. Draw nodes as (labeled) squares, and pointers as arrows (the links as arrows from one square to another). Erase and redraw the arrows as you modify them in the code.